How to Draw the shortest path
I am using flutter application Currently this code is drawing a path that prioritizes the fastest time, but the distance will be longer. What do I need to do to make this code draw the shortest path from point A to point B?
getPoly(change, lat, lng) async {
    fmpoly.clear();
    if ((userRequestData.isEmpty ||
            userRequestData['accepted_at'] == null ||
            userRequestData['is_driver_arrived'] == 1) &&
        lat == '') {
      for (var i = 1; i < addressList.length; i++) {
        var api = await http.get(Uri.parse(
            'https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-car/route/v1/driving/${addressList[i - 1].latlng.longitude},${addressList[i - 1].latlng.latitude};${addressList[i].latlng.longitude},${addressList[i].latlng.latitude}?overview=false&geometries=polyline&steps=true'));
        if (api.statusCode == 200) {
          // ignore: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers
          List _poly = jsonDecode(api.body)['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'];
          // String polystring = _poly[5]['geometry'];
          polyline.clear();
          for (var e in _poly) {
            decodeEncodedPolyline(e['geometry']);
            // polystring = polystring + _poly[i]['geometry'];
          }

          double lat = (addressList[0].latlng.latitude +
                  addressList[addressList.length - 1].latlng.latitude) /
              2;
          double lon = (addressList[0].latlng.longitude +
                  addressList[addressList.length - 1].latlng.longitude) /
              2;
          var val = LatLng(lat, lon);
          // if(change == true){
          _fmController.move(fmlt.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude), 13);

          setState(() {});
        }
      }
    } else {
      var api = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-car/route/v1/driving/$lng,$lat;${addressList[0].latlng.longitude},${addressList[0].latlng.latitude}?overview=false&geometries=polyline&steps=true'));
      if (api.statusCode == 200) {
        // ignore: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers
        List _poly = jsonDecode(api.body)['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'];
        polyline.clear();
        for (var e in _poly) {
          decodeEncodedPolyline(e['geometry']);
        }
        // ignore: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers
        double _lat = (addressList[0].latlng.latitude + lat) / 2;
        // ignore: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers
        double _lon = (addressList[0].latlng.longitude + lng) / 2;
        var val = LatLng(_lat, _lon);
        // if(change == true){
        _fmController.move(fmlt.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude), 15);
        // }
        setState(() {});
      } else {}
    }
    fmPolyGot = false;
  }

